# Print only table data in popup jquery

Tags: jquery, printing, html-table

All my below code section show table in which i'm feeding data from ajax, my data is displayed in custom popup inside a dynamic created table; 
in custom popup there is a print button on print button click I want to print the table filled with ajax data displayed in tabular formatted  in same popup to be printed. Please help me.

```
function printPreview(i){
             var id=i;     
             var flag=new Array();
                if(checkstatus[i]=="B"){
                        send={address:'http://192.168.1.22:8082/oracledetail/test.php?result=8&table_code='+tableCode[i]}
                        $.ajax({
                            type:"POST",
                            url:"dummytest.php",
                            data:send,
                            success: function(data)
                            {          
                                //alert(data);
                                //centering with css
                                centerPopup();
                                //load popup
                                loadPopup();                                
                                $('#popupContact').html("<a id='popupContactClose'>X</a><h1>Print Bill</h1>"+
                                "<center>"+         
                                "<table id='printView' cellspacing='15px'>"+
                                    "<tr class='rows'>"+
                                        "<td><b><font size='+1'>Sr. No</font></b></td>"+
                                        "<td><b><font size='+1'>Item Name</font></b></td>"+
                                        "<td><b><font size='+1'>Quantity</font></b></td>"+
                                        "<td><b><font size='+1'>Price/Item</font></b></td>"+
                                        "<td><b><font size='+1' style='padding-left:10px;'>Qty*Price</font></b></td>"+
                                    "</tr>"+            
                                "</table>"+ "<br/> <input id='print' type='button' value='Print Bill' />"   +               
                                "</center>"                             
                                 ); 
                                $("#popupContact").delegate('#print',"click",function(){
                                    var tabcode=tableCode[id];
                                    printBill(tabcode);
                                });
                                $("#popupContact").delegate('#popupContactClose',"click",function(){
                                    disablePopup();
                                    location.reload();
                                });
                                var total = 0;                   
                                var responseString=data.split(",");
                                var len= responseString.length;                             
                                for(var i=0;i<len-1;i++){                                   
                                    var orderDetails=responseString[i].split("~");
                                    itemName[i]=orderDetails[0];                            
                                    itemQuantity[i]=orderDetails[1];
                                    priceperItem[i]=orderDetails[2];
                                    itemtotalPrice[i]=orderDetails[3];  
                                    total += parseInt(itemtotalPrice[i]);
                                    $('#printView').append("<tr class='rows'> <td class='srno'><font size='+1' style='text-align=center;'>"+(i+1)+"</font></td>    <td class='itemname'><font size='+1'>"+itemName[i]+"</font></td>  <td class='quantity'><font size='+1'>"+itemQuantity[i]+"</font></td>  <td class='price'> <font size='+1'>"+priceperItem[i]+"</font></td>  <td class='itemtotalprice'><font size='+1'>"+itemtotalPrice[i]+"</font></td> </tr>");    
                                    if(i==len-2){
                                        $('#printView').append("<tr>   <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td>    <td> <label> <h3 > Total Bill : "+ total +" </h3> </label>");
                                    }
                                }//for ends.                                

                            }//function ends
                    }); //ajax ends                         
                }//if ends   
                else{                   
                    $('#popupContact').html("<center><h2>Billing Request Not Yet Generated<h2></center>");
                }
        }//function ends..
```

This is my popup that display data and want to print this data only in this custom:

[image]

Actually when I click on print I am executing this below code for print:

```
$("#popupContact").delegate('#print',"click",function(){
                                    var tabcode=tableCode[id];
                                    printBill(tabcode);
                                    var display_setting="toolbar=yes,location=no,directories=yes,menubar=yes,";  
                                    display_setting+="scrollbars=yes,width=750, height=600, left=100, top=25"; 
                                    var content_innerhtml = document.getElementById("#printView").innerHTML;  
                                    var document_print=window.open("","",display_setting);  
                                    document_print.document.open();  
                                    document_print.document.write(content_innerhtml);  
                                    document_print.print();  
                                    document_print.document.close();
                                    location.reload();  
                                });
```

but when I debug it it show me error at this line:

```
line: --> `var content_innerhtml = document.getElementById("#printView").innerHTML;`
```

> error : -->document.getElementById("#printView") is null

and further execution stop and direct `location.reload();`
reload the page.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content_innerhtml = document.getElementById("#printView").innerHTML;
```

should be

```
var content_innerhtml = document.getElementById("printView").innerHTML;
```

Comment: thnx prowla but this code open extra document  that is tp be printed i need only settings box for just printing data